# Why is Google translator skipping some text in Python?

Tags: python, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am trying to translate text which is partly in Japanese and partly in English into English. My problem is that after applying the translate function, some text from the original text seems to be missing.

As can be seen from the code and output,

> At present only SDS of about 20 to 30% of HAZMAT of the product is
>   obtained

seems to be missing from the output.

**Code**

```
translator.translate(   
'At present only SDS of about 20 to 30% of HAZMAT of the product is obtained.  
Chemicals management (Japan) Qn 4.03 Business operators are responsible for ensuring that necessary information is readily recognized at each workplace dealing with substances specified as requiring safety data sheets (SDS) under the Occupational Safety and Health Act , Or make it known to workers handling such substances. 入手済みのSDSはPandashで確認することが出来る。MTEが使用する化学物質についてはSDSが入手されている。PCコメント(2017/07/10)SDSを入手する基準ですが、すべての商品に対して入手する、というのが原則ではあります。ただし、現在販売されているすべての商品に対して一度にSDSを入手することも難しいため、再判定になったときはSDSの提出をお願いし、ご提出いただいております。なお、もしも何らかの事情でSDSをご提出いただけない場合は、MSDS Exemption',  
src='ja', dest='en').text
```

**Output**

```
'Chemicals management (Japan) Qn 4.03 Business operators are responsible for ensuring that each information is readily recognized at each workplace dealing with substances specified as requiring safety data sheets ( SDS) under the Occupational Safety and Health Act, Or make it known hand to such workers. The obtained SDS can be confirmed with Pandash. For chemical substances used by MTE, SDS has been obtained. PC comment (2017/07/10) It is the standard to obtain SDS, but in principle it is to obtain for all items. However, it is difficult to acquire SDS at the same time for all the products currently on sale, so if you decide to reevaluate it, we ask you to submit SDS and submit it. In addition, if you are unable to submit SDS for any reason, MSDS Exemption'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a formatting issue, possibly because there is a line break (`\n`) character in your text. To solve this, surround your text with triple quotes (`"""`) which allows for multi-line input.

The following seems to give your desired output:

**Code:**

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

translator.translate(
"""At present only SDS of about 20 to 30% of HAZMAT of the product is obtained.
Chemicals management (Japan) Qn 4.03 Business operators are responsible for ensuring that necessary information is readily recognized at each workplace dealing with substances specified as requiring safety data sheets (SDS) under the Occupational Safety and Health Act , Or make it known to workers handling such substances. 入手済みのSDSはPandashで確認することが出来る。MTEが使用する化学物質についてはSDSが入手されている。PCコメント(2017/07/10)SDSを入手する基準ですが、すべての商品に対して入手する、というのが原則ではあります。ただし、現在販売されているすべての商品に対して一度にSDSを入手することも難しいため、再判定になったときはSDSの提出をお願いし、ご提出いただいております。なお、もしも何らかの事情でSDSをご提出いただけない場合は、MSDS Exemption""",
src='ja', dest='en').text
```

**Output:**

At present only SDS of about 20 to 30% of HAZMAT of the product is obtained.
Chemicals management (Japan) Qn 4.03 Business operators are each responsible for each requiring safety data sheets (SDS) under the Occupational Safety and Health Act, Or make it known to workers handling such The obtained SDS can be confirmed with Pandash. For chemical substances used by MTE, SDS has been obtained. PC comment (2017/07/10) It is the standard to obtain SDS, but in principle it is to obtain for all items. However, it is difficult to acquire SDS at the same time for all the products currently on sale, so if you decide to reevaluate it, we ask you to submit SDS and submit it. In addition, if you are unable to submit SDS for any reason, MSDS Exemption

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Python. Could you tell me how I would replicate it if this was for a column? and not just one example that I showed here

Comment: What do you mean when you say column? Please add further explanation and an example, if possible.

Comment: I use this code to translate the text in my column description_correctiveaction to English. 
raw_data_non_english['translated_text_1'] = raw_data_non_english['description_correctiveaction'].apply(translator.translate, dest='en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))                                                                What change would I require to resolve the formatting issue?

Comment: @RoopaliLalwani It is unclear what you mean by *column*. You can try to explain further, or if you have a new question that is different from this one, please write a new question for it. If you send a link here I will do my best to answer it for you as well. Next time, try to describe your situation fully to receive an answer that solves all of your issues.

Comment: Please refrain from changing an already answered and accepted question as this could be confusing for future readers. If you realize your original question did not help solve your issue (an XY problem) please ask a new question that is more specific.

Comment: I will do my best to answer your new question to the best of my ability

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54284093/how-to-fix-googletrans-translate-output